# Allow <tr/> inside a div to allow for dom append to table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I ajax fetch a bunch of table rows contained in a div box, to be appended to a table on page. However `<tr/>` not being direct children of `<table/>`, but being children of `<div/>` get removed from page & just the content inside the tr is there. I want to keep the tr in the dom even so that I could do appends to table.

Table already on page:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> (title and Location here)</th>
        <th>Expires in </th> 
        <th>Views</th> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to keep the html as shown below on page so that I should append the rows inside the div(shown below) to above table using javascript

```
<div>
    <tr>
         <td> a
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> b
         </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

How do I prevent tr from being hidden from page ?

Comment: This question is quite difficult to understand. A code example would be very helpful.

Comment: Considering you'll end up with invalid HTML if you append it directly, I suggest you extract the table rows and append it to the table.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML Table Row Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/tr)

> Permitted parent elements:
>    `A <table>, <thead>, <tbody> or <tfoot> element.`

Having a `<tr>` element as a child of a `<div>` is invalid HTML, so the browser removes it.

Also, having a `<div>` directly inside a `<table>` is invalid as well.

To fix your problem, remove the wrapping `<div>`, or extract the `<tr>`s before appending to the `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just include a `<table>` tag inside the `<div>`, and pull the `<tr>`s from inside it when you need them.  For that matter, there isn't much that you can do with the div that you couldn't do with `<table>`.